# Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio Code is not synched when new folders/files are created in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, synchronization

I'm currently working for a new company, where most of the guys develop in Visual Studio 2017 (vs2017). I really like it, but feel more comfortable working with Visual Studio Code (vscode), and because, my work does not require any build processes.

Here's the workflow: I've put the workspace folder in `C:/` directory, and open it through vscode. Whenever I apply code changes, the results are visible in vs2017 IDE. But when I create new folders/files in vscode, I don't see it in vs2017...

And because files/folders are not synched, I feel stuck using vs2017. An alternative is to do these operations on vs2017, and code in vscode. But I don't see this as a beneficial and efficient in hindsight.

To summerize, how can I create files/folders in vscode, or lets say in sublime/atom/brackets for that matter, and see it in vs2017?

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my question can be found [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-files-created-outside-of-Visual-Studio-not-show-up-in-the-Solution-Explorer-unless-you-add-them-manually).

In short, you have to enable **show all files** in solution explorer in vs2017, then right click on the newly added folder (marked in gray), and click **include in project**.

I recommend doing this everytime you open vs2017.

PS! Open for other alternatives where you can skip this process, it may be stress to do this when project scales.